# How to sort php results alphabetically?

Tags: php

I just started using PHP last week. I was trying to find out how to point at a folder of images and return thumbnails with links to larger images. After doing some research I found a script that will let me do exactly what I need, almost.

Here is the code I have:

```
$files = glob("Bookcase/*.*"); 

for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) 
{
     $num = $files[$i];
     echo '<a href="' . $num . ' " target="_blank"><img class="thumb" img src="'.$num.'"></a>'."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";      
}
```

The only thing this script doesn't do for me is sort the images alphabetically. I don't know near enough about PHP yet to do much of anything. How can I accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as glob should return the pathes sorted. Would you show us the order you get and the order you expect?

Comment: The folder I am pointing at has images starting (for now) with the letters a, c, e, m, w. This script keeps returning them in the order c, w, m, a, e. I would like it to return the images in a, b, c, etc.

Comment: Have you tried to sort them after you fetched them?

Comment: Thought you had to supply the `GLOB_NOSORT` flag to not have it sorted. What is `var_dump($files);`?

Comment: I figured it out. Some of the images start with a lower case and some capital. I changed all to lower case and guess what......like I said I am really new to all of this.

Comment: Ah, so it sorts by ASCII values (?), and not by actual letters. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = glob("images/*.*"); 
sort($files);
$lenth = count($files);
for ($i=0; $i<$lenth; $i++){
   //your code
}
```

Use this code to sort your images alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = glob("Bookcase/*.*"); 
$myarr = array();
foreach($files as $file){
$myarr[$file];
}
sort($file);

$clength = count($file);
for($i = 0; $i < $clength; $i++) {
    $num = $file[$i];
     echo '<a href="' . $num . ' " target="_blank"><img class="thumb" img src="'.$num.'"></a>'."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";      
}
```